# Reset an Array in PHP within a loop after an element of it has been unset within a loop

Tags: php

```
  foreach($value as $key=>$val){
     unset($val);
  }
```

I want to reset the array index back to `0,1...length($value)-1` after unseting 
the first value.

Please let know about possible solutions.

Comment: So: in case $key goes up from 0 to 5, you want to have the $key back to 0 when the foreach is done?

Answer (score 0):

```
array_shift($value);
```

> array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it,
>   shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All
>   numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero
>   while literal keys won't be touched.

Comment: @Elementary    foreach($value as $key=>$val){
            array_shift($value); break;
        }